# jquery datepicker set date to tomorrow's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have set the date for #arrival to todays date, but how can I set the #departure to tomorrow's date?

```
 $(function() {

$( "#arrival" ).datepicker({

dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
yearRange: ":2016",
minDate: "dateToday",


onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#departure" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}

});
$(function() {
    $("#arrival").datepicker("setDate", "0");
});


$( "#departure" ).datepicker({

dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
numberOfMonths: 2,
yearRange: ":2016",

});

$(function() {
    $("#departure").datepicker("setDate", "1");
});

});
```

I have customized the datepicker and it works fine.

Comment: Should'nt it work the way it is -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JSFXP/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the change function of the first datepicker, create a date object, set the date one day forward, and set the date of the second datepicker to that date. You can use `minDate` to make sure any date earlier than the set date can not be picked.

```
$(function () {
    $("#arrival").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        yearRange: ":2016",
        minDate: "dateToday",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
                myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+1); 
            $('#departure').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
        }
    });

    $("#departure").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        yearRange: ":2016",
    });

    $("#arrival").datepicker("setDate", "0");
    $("#departure").datepicker("setDate", "1");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JSFXP/1/)

Comment: just add
$( "#departure" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", myDate);
at the end on close to have the minimum date so you can't go back