# Set current day active on datepickers with Jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a small problem setting the correct dates on my datepickers. 
Somehow the date shown in the textbox are not the correct one in the datepicker.

**Code textboxes:**

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
    @Html.Label("Departure Date:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new { Value = Model.DepartureDate.ToShortDateString(), @class = "textbox", @id = "departureDate" })
</div>

<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
   @Html.Label("Return Date:", new { @class = "label-travel" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnDate, new { Value = Model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString(), @class = "textbox", @id = "returnDate" }) 
</div>

var currentDay = ??
var currentDayPlusOne = ??

$("#departureDate").datepicker({
    dateformat: "yy-dd-mm"
});

$("#returnDate").datepicker({
    dateformat: "yy-dd-mm"
});
```

What should I write in order to set the current days in my datepicker, so the textbox has the date 2015-26-15 and the other day is 2015-27-15?

Hope someone can show me.

Comment: Do you want something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591634/jquery-datepicker-set-date-to-tomorrows-date and related fidller http://jsfiddle.net/JSFXP/1/

Comment: What kind of date is `2015-26-15`? Is there a calendar with 15 or 27 months?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this snippet:

Here, `setDate` sets today date & `dateFormat` defines which format you want to show.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();  
var tomrw = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$("#departureDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-dd-mm"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
$("#returnDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-dd-mm"}).datepicker("setDate", tomrw);
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Departure date:
<input type="text" id="departureDate" />
Return date:
<input type="text" id="returnDate" />
```

You could also use `setDate : 1` for setting tomorrow's date. As the value 1 means that it's one day from current date. If you want to the departure date to 10 days from the current date you can use `setDate : 10`.

Comment: Works.. but is it right to call datepicker 2 times?

Comment: @Mandersen Of course, you can call `datepicker()` as many times on different elements. Look at the [Date Range](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) sample on jquery datepicker example which uses `from` and `to` fields as datepickers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
<script>
                $("#departureDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

            $("#returnDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
</script>
```

Comment: The second datepicker does the same thing as the first one and the OP wants the returnDate set to one day apart from today's date. so your code won't work. ;(

Comment: @Lucky I know but there is no any specification regarding this. so i have not added code for that.