# set datepicker default date to the first saturday available?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker input that i want to fill automatically with the first day of saturday available.

F.E.  today is 19/09/2016  i want to show 24/09/2016 in the label of the input

which is the code to add after  "defaultdate:"  to do so?!

I already set the datepicker to show only the saturday of the month when clicked but the defualt date is locked to the current day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery datepicker set date to tomorrow's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591634/jquery-datepicker-set-date-to-tomorrows-date)

Comment: You can use this script: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/find-next-occurring-friday-or-any-dayofweek

Comment: my case is different ... to have the tomorrow's day you just need to add  "defaultDate. +1; "  in the code

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how can you do in jquery. but i did in c#. if you want to get first monday, tuesday ....  of week just use, if you want to get next monday, u can adddays(7).

```
public DateTime GetNextWeekday(DayOfWeek day)
{
   DateTime result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    while( result.DayOfWeek != day )
        result = result.AddDays(1);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Saturday of this week by below code and set date in date picker which you have used.

```
var dateObj= new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6 - dateObj.getDay();
dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

DatePicker Configuration

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({}); 
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", numberOfDaysToAdd );
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59s5wdb9/1/)

Comment: this was helpfull, I'll post the complete answare to my case

Answer (score 0):

I found the prefect solution :

```
   jQuery('input#date').datepicker('setDate',  get_first_saturday(new Date));
    function get_first_saturday(d) {
        var day = d.getDay();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6 - day;
                firstsaturday= d.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd  ;
        return new Date(d.setDate(firstsaturday));
    }
```