# How to Fix Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

How to set today date and tomorrow date for Datepicker?

[JS File here](https://www.connectingserver.com/test/)

Image in website

[image: X]

Comment: Post all relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the current date of the [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), use the `setDate`option.

This can be done on the fly with `$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date() )` ([soucre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/751843/1152809))

If you want to set the date to tomorrow, use `$("#dateselector").datepicker("setDate", "1");` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591848/1152809))

Or you can use setDate when you're first setting up your datepicker with:

```
$('#dateselector').datepicker({'setDate': new Date()});
```

These sources were found with a very easy Google search. Typically, when posting a question, you want to show your code, what you've tried, and what errors you're getting. Good Luck!

Comment: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) By not providing code, as you yourself state, the question is off topic. You should be voting to close, not answering it.